Inserting a prefix "MFI" in front of comma delimited values in a cell
I have a cell with comma delimited values that I want to add a prefix (MFI) to each of the values before combining these with values from another cell.
For example, Cell A2 contains comma separated values 1234,2356,5689,5678,6547,2589. I want to add a prefix MFI to each of these values so that they look like this MFI 1234, MFI 2356, MFI 5689, MFI 5678, MFI 6547, MFI 2589. =CONCATENATE("MFI ";B2) only adds the prefix to the first value and not the others. The number of values varies from row to row within the column

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Cell 1 contains MFIcell A2 contains

Cell A2 contains comma separated values1234,2356,5689,5678,6547,2589. I want to add a prefix MFI to each of these values so that they look like this MFI 1234, MFI 2356, MFI 5689, MFI 5678, MFI 6547, MFI 2589.   =CONCATENATE("MFI ";B2) only adds the prefix to the first value and not the others. The number of values varies from row to row within the column. Hopefully that makes more sense

You can use this formula:
=TEXTJOIN(",",,"MFI "&TEXTSPLIT(B2,","))


Split the value in cell B2 into an single-row array using comma as the delimiter
Concatenate the string "MFI " with the array - this concatenates the string with each element separately
Join the array using comma as the delimiter



Still get that error message saying there is something wrong with the formula

What error message?

If you have 365, try:
=ARRAYTOTEXT("MFI "&TEXTSPLIT(B1,,","))

If you don't have 365, you can write a User Defined Function (UDF) in VBA.
To enter this User Defined Function (UDF), alt-F11 opens the Visual Basic Editor.
Ensure your project is highlighted in the Project Explorer window.
Then, from the top menu, select Insert/Module and
paste the code below into the window that opens.
To use this User Defined Function (UDF), enter a formula like =vbaTextJoin(B1) in some cell.
Option Explicit
Function vbaTextJoin(str As String, Optional sPrefix As String = "MFI ") As String
    Dim SplitIt() As String
    Dim I As Long
    
SplitIt = Split(str, ",")
For I = 0 To UBound(SplitIt)
    SplitIt(I) = sPrefix & SplitIt(I)
Next I

vbaTextJoin = Join(SplitIt, ", ")

End Function

Note that this UDF allows you to optionally specify a different Prefix.

Are you looking for each value to be in it's own cell. Looking kind of like.

It would be a one off update but use Text to Columns with the formulas provided above.

